# Measuring the goodness of fit of a constrained regression using GLM in Python

Tags: python, regression, glm

I'm using GLM to run a constrained regression in Python and want to try to get a measure of the 'goodness of fit' of the regression.  If I was running an OLS regression I would use R squared, however I cannot get the rsquared from the GLM regression as from what I read it does not seem to be appropriate to use.

I've looked around and found that it has been suggested to create a pseudo r squared, for example dividing residual deviance/null deviance, but note there are a number of different ways to calculate such a measure.

An example of my regression:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm    
modelVQM = sm.GLM(Y,X)
results = model.fit_constrained((ConsX,ConsVal))
```

Where X is six columns of data, Y is one column of data and ConsX/ConsVal refers to the regression constraints.

Comment: I use numpy to calculate R-squared as "R-squared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(regression_error) / numpy.var(dependent_data))"

Comment: @mattaj247, Do you use GLM without split data to train/test parts?